# How to set npm root path to .../Appdata/roaming/npm

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular5

I have installed `nodejs ->8.12.0` and `npm ->6.4.1` and trying to install angular 1.7.4
I have added environment variable path to

> C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm

and

> C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin

but when i run `npm root -g` it shows current directory path, not the path i set
Nodejs is install to

> C:\Program Files\nodejs

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to set the global path to roaming.  Go to:

`C:\Users\YOURNAME\.npmrc`

and locate `NPMRC`.  Edit the file to:

`C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm`

If `.npmrc` is not visible you will end to show your hidden files

Comment: When I am running yarn create I am getting No such file or directory. ```C:\users\rashid\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: No such file or directory```. And when I check ```$ npm root -g``` I could see the correct path, but still seeing the above error.
```C:\Users\rashid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules```