# When I try to check appium version with 'appium -v' I receive command not found. What can I do?

Tags: python-appium

When I try to check appium version with `'appium -v'` I receive command not found. What can I do? 
I tried different options but it's not working

Comment: Which operating system are you using? How did you install it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Mac OS try

> appium --version

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, make sure to add npm to your path: `C:...\AppData\Roaming\npm`

You can check on how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53476780/4103101)

If you are on Linux/Mac, then I suggest to renistall node/npm with [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installation-and-update) and then reinstall appium with `npm install appium -g`